# How to run a python program from a bash script on startup?

Tags: raspbian, python, bash

I have a python script that is located at `/etc/testscripts/WebServer`. I call this usually from the command line by calling `sudo python3.6 /etc/testscripts/WebServer`.

I have a bash script that looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

nohup python3.6 /etc/testscripts/WebServer
```

The name of this bash file is `/etc/testscripts/startwebserver.sh`.

How can I get this to execute on startup? The unit is running headless so no users are logging in. I did this before by adding `sudo python3.6 /etc/testscripts/WebServer` to `/etc/rc.local` but I want to run this via a bash script so that I can modify it later if needed by just changing the bash script rather than modifying rc.local.

I tried adding `sudo /etc/testscripts/startwebserver.sh &` to rc.local and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo` needs an interaction, password... That's why it fails. And `sudo` isn't needed when running in rc.local.

Comment: @MatsK Should I just change it to `/etc/testscripts/startwebserver.sh &` then in rc.local? Also, is the `&` needed in rc.local or should I put that in the bash script? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The trailing `&` informs the shell to put the process `startwebserver.sh` in the background. Without the `&` rc.local will wait for the `startwebserver.sh`to complete before it processes the rest of `rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Here is my setup:

/etc/rc.local:

```
/etc/testscripts/startwebserver.sh &
```

startwebserver.sh:

```
python3.6 /etc/testscripts/WebServer &
```

Comment: Hmmm, to use my comment and the post that as an answer is not encouraging me to assist you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `sudo` from `rc.local`. Sudo needs an interaction, you need to type in the password and that's not possible when the system is booting.